# Team is or Team are

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say, the team that will be attending with me is listed below: or should I say the team that will be attending with me are listed below

Comment: This is not clear...are they multiple teams, one team, or team members? And is this British English, or American?

Comment: In your case, you probably should go with "the team members are listed below."

Comment: The sales team that will be attending with me is or are listed below

Comment: Depends on whether the team is in the US or, instead, the team are in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a team is [a count noun](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/team). You can have two teams, ten teams, or one team. So if you're talking about *the team*, or one team, then that should take a singular verb:

> The team ... is listed below.

American English follows this basic rule, but British English allows one to apply plural verbs to "team" when it's understood that the team is acting independently. That's why this [British source](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/common-problems-count-and-uncount-nouns) allows one to use seemingly singular group nouns (like *team*) with a plural verb. Hence in British English you could also say:

> The team ... are listed below.

Finally, if the choice causes anxiety and you want to be explicit about listing names, you can go with something like what Robusto suggested in the comments:

> The team members attending with me are listed below.
>
> The people attending with me are listed below.
>
> The colleagues attending with me are listed below.

Answer (score 0):

**Team is** is correct. **Team are** sounds weird to my ears (wow it rhymes).  :)

If you do want to use **are**, use **team members**.

Thanks